# Is there a way to compare the efficiency of a for loop to the 'loops' of a list comprehension? Will they be identical?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-for-loop

I'm not asking about the actual time to calculation.

In a nested for loop, you can count the number of times you step into the innermost for loop, and measure efficiency that way.

Can this be done with a list comprehension?

My actual code may or may not be helpful.

Nested For-loop : --------------------------------

```
    scanWindowSize = len(B) - 1
    mylist = []
    loopsteps = 0
    
    for scanWindowSize in range(len(B),0,-1):
        for i in range(len(B) - scanWindowSize + 1):
            if B[i:i + scanWindowSize] in C:
                mylist.append([B[i:i + scanWindowSize]])
    
    
                loopsteps += 1
    
    if len(mylist) > 0:
        break
```

List comprehension nested within a For-loop: -----------------

```
    for scanWindowSize in range(len(B),0,-1):
        mylist = [B[i:i + scanWindowSize] for i in range(len(B) - scanWindowSize + 1) if B[i:i + scanWindowSize] in C]
        if mylist:
            break
```

- This code compares substrings of string B to string C
  to find the largest string (or strings) that appear
  in each string, and returns a list of that string or string(s)

---

outer for loop executes once for each size of substring
of B (unless we hit break)
for each character position in the current substring,
take the substring beginning at that character position
and of the current scanWindowSize,
and append it to mylist if it appears in C
increment loopsteps by 1 to count the number of times
we enter the inner for loop*

Comment: Algorithmically you're doing the exact same thing, so they're equivalent from a big-O standpoint -- both are O(len(B)^2*len(C)).  Using a comprehension vs a `for` might affect the efficiency by a constant factor but you're looping over the same number of elements either way.

Comment: When you find you asking which way is the more efficient, the answer lies in the `timeit` module. It is specially crafted to run a code a number of time to easily give representative benchmarks.

Comment: Thank you Samwise, this confirms what I was supposing, but had yet been unsure of.